# Can i schedule notification in swift after app is fully terminated?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

I am working on an app where I need to send users 8 local notifications per day. However, due to the limit of 64 notifications, I need to ensure that notifications are rescheduled if the user doesn't open the app. My goal is to reschedule notifications weekly.

Is it possible to schedule local notifications even if the user doesn't open the app for months? I want to schedule notifications for the current week and then, after one week, schedule notifications for the following week, and so on.

Comment: You could use push notifications instead of local notifications, but if the user doesn't open your app regularly then they probably don't want notifications from it either.

Comment: What API are you using for scheduling notifications?

Comment: @cutiko i am using UNUserNotificationCenter for triggering local notification

Comment: Can share the code you are registering those eight notifications?